# Java Hashmap getting only 3 url from text,even If text has multiple url

Tags: java

I am trying to print hashmap by providing text file(attached in this message) which should print hashmap(url,0),(url,1).. but I am able to get only 3 url from text.. i am not able to get rest all url and it's Index. could some one please help me in this.

```
-----------------Code------------------------------------------------



import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class  ArticleIndexer{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


        File file = new File("src\\article2content.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        scanAndPrint(scan,"guardian");  
        //scan.close();





    }

    private static boolean matchServer(String url ,String str)
    {



        if (url.toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase()) && (url != null)&&(str!=null))
        {
             return true;   
        }
        else{
            return  false;
        }
    }

    public static void scanAndPrint(Scanner in) throws FileNotFoundException {


        String page = in.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\A")).next();
        //System.out.println(page.length());
        int beg = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < page.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (i + "<a href=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a Href=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a hRef=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a hrEf=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a hreF=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<A href=".length() <= page.length())
            {
                String tag = page.substring(i, i +8);
                if (tag.equals("<a href=") || tag.equals("<a Href=") || tag.equals("<a hRef=") || tag.equals("<a hrEf=") || tag.equals("<a hreF=") || tag.equals("<A href=")) 
                    beg = i;
            }
            if (i + "\">".length() <= page.length())
            {
                String tag = page.substring(i, i + 2);
                if ((tag.equals("\">") || tag.equals("\">")) && beg != -1) 
                { 
                    String tt= page.substring(beg + 9, i);

                        String[] array=tt.split("\"");
                        String Url= array[0];
                        Url=MyURL.parseURL(Url);

                            System.out.println(Url);
                    beg = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        in.close();
    }



    public static void scanAndPrint(Scanner in, String str) throws FileNotFoundException {

        //HashMap<String , Integer>= new HashMap<>
        HashMap<String, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
//      String page = in.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\A")).next();
//      //System.out.println(page.length());
//      int beg = -1;
//      for (int i = 0; i < page.length(); i++) 
//      {
//          if (i + "<a href=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a Href=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a hRef=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a hrEf=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a hreF=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<A href=".length() <= page.length())
//          {
//              String tag = page.substring(i, i +8);
//              if (tag.equals("<a href=") || tag.equals("<a Href=") || tag.equals("<a hRef=") || tag.equals("<a hrEf=") || tag.equals("<a hreF=") || tag.equals("<A href=")) 
//                  beg = i;
//          }
//          if (i + "\">".length() <= page.length())
//          {
//              String tag = page.substring(i, i + 2);
//              if ((tag.equals("\">") || tag.equals("\">")) && beg != -1) 
//              { 
//                  String tt= page.substring(beg + 9, i); 
//                  
//                      String[] array=tt.split("\"");
//                      String Url= array[0];
//                      Url=MyURL.parseURL(Url);
//                      
//                      System.out.println(Url);
//                      if(matchServer(Url,str)==true)


        String page = in.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\\A")).next();
        //System.out.println(page.length());
        int beg = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < page.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (i + "<a href=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a Href=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a hRef=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a hrEf=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<a hreF=".length() <= page.length() || i + "<A href=".length() <= page.length())
            {
                String tag = page.substring(i, i +8);
                if (tag.equals("<a href=") || tag.equals("<a Href=") || tag.equals("<a hRef=") || tag.equals("<a hrEf=") || tag.equals("<a hreF=") || tag.equals("<A href=")) 
                    beg = i;
            }
            if (i + "\">".length() <= page.length())
            {
                String tag = page.substring(i, i + 2);
                if ((tag.equals("\">") || tag.equals("\">")) && beg != -1) 
                { 
                    String tt= page.substring(beg + 9, i);

                        String[] array=tt.split("\"");
                        String Url= array[0];
                        Url=MyURL.parseURL(Url);
                        if(matchServer(Url,str)==true)
                        {
                            //System.out.println(Url);

                            for(int j = 0; j < Url.length(); j++)
                            {
                                hmap.put(Url, j);

                                for (String s : hmap.keySet())
                                    System.out.println( s+ " " + hmap.get(s));
                            }

                        }

                        beg = -1;
                }

            }

        }

    }



    }





Thanks.
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Your code is not complete: `MyURL cannot be resolved`

Comment: have tried debugging.. nothing help..i put last for loop inside if statement..now, i am getting 74 index but Url is same..

Comment: Could you please try with below                                                                                   "<p><a href="http://www.eboladeeply.org" title="">Ebola Deeply</a>, a new single-issue website from the team behind <a href="http://www.syriadeeply.org" title="">Syria Deeply</a>, could help to rectify this situation. As with Syria Deeply, the site offers a mixture of original reporting and aggregation, from a team made up of journalists"           this text and try..

Comment: Could anyone please look into above issue.. if something is not able to understand.. do let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use Jsoup library to parse from a website ?

Perhaps helpful.

https://jsoup.org/

```
package org.jsoup.examples;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
* Example program to list links from a URL.
*/
public class ListLinks {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
    String url = args[0];
    print("Fetching %s...", url);

    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
    Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");

    print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
    for (Element src : media) {
        if (src.tagName().equals("img"))
            print(" * %s: <%s> %sx%s (%s)",
                    src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"),   src.attr("width"), src.attr("height"),
                    trim(src.attr("alt"), 20));
        else
            print(" * %s: <%s>", src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"));
    }

    print("\nImports: (%d)", imports.size());
    for (Element link : imports) {
        print(" * %s <%s> (%s)", link.tagName(),link.attr("abs:href"), link.attr("rel"));
    }

    print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
    for (Element link : links) {
        print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
    }
}

private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
    System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
}

  private static String trim(String s, int width) {
    if (s.length() > width)
        return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
    else
        return s;
  }
}
```